# Alternative messaging network to WhatsApp?

Tags: android, ios, chat

Since Facebook bought [Whatsapp](http://www.whatsapp.com/), I'm looking for an alternative app and chat network which is able to replace their functionality. What can you recommend?

Requirements:

- [End-to-end encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption)
- group chat
- search contacts in address book of the phone
- Ad free
- can cost up to € 2 once
- share photos, videos
- nice to have video chat
- Android and iOS support

Are there any alternatives available?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for alternative *software* to access the Whatsapp messaging network, or are you looking for an alternative messaging *network?*

Comment: Erm... Another network? I do not know that it would be possible to access the whatsapp network with another client.

Comment: That's what I was trying to clarify. "Alternative software \*to\* Whatsapp" doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: Another network, which is independent of whatsapp. That's what I'm looking for. A network like BBM.

Comment: Similar if not same features are included in Viber, but since I don’t use it I wont make and recommendation of it. Just point in a possible direction.

Comment: does Google Hangout sound good to you? they have a group video call though. Point to point encryption you mean chat are not saved on could? skype?

Comment: It should operate like What'sapp. Skype does not.

Comment: Do you mean that WhatsApp provides an end-to-end encryption? Also FYI WhatsApp encryption is not perfect: http://support.pandasecurity.com/blog/security/whatsapp-is-insecure-myth-or-reality/

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt Yes I do. ;-)

Comment: I'm surprised [Kik](http://kik.com/) hasn't made the list, it does allow a series of different "plugins" that may be of use.

Comment: How can "Desktop client" not be on the feature list :( This is why I refuse to use WhatsApp nowadays.

Comment: You can have a look at [Tango](http://www.tango.me/) as well. I believe it has all you need, but can't really say much about it. I've only used it to talk to couple of friends abroad. It had a better connection than Viber, most of the times, but the application itself seemed quite buggy to me, so I've deleted it. From ppl around me that have used it as well heard that it has something like its own social network and you can even connect to ppl that are near by (location wise), but you've never met...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a protocol, [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) (formerly known as Jabber) would fulfill a lot of these requirements ([Possibly because WhatsApp *is* using XMPP on the backend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp#Technical))

It *is* massively extendible, so I'm picking a specific client that covers a lot of these requirements. Its impossible to cover *all* since things like being able to pick a contact on your address book is because whatsapp simply uses a phone number as a username.

Other than video and group chat, *any* jabber client with [OTR](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/) would do - I'd recommend [chatsecure](https://chatsecure.org/) - it does seem to do multi user chat (though not chatrooms) without OTR, and runs on your two target platforms (and you can use pidgin or kopete on the desktop side for OTR conversations).

Its free, can send photos and videos the usual way and does everything but search contacts in address book of the phone.

Video would be covered by jingle, but I can't seem to find a good, well recommended android client outside the old obsolete google talk.

Comment: I've used Jabber but my experience with it is that it's currently not a valid replacement for WhatsApp: its support for asynchronous/disconnected operation is just not up to the task.  Basically, unless you're very lucky in the server (and client) you use, messages only get through if both the sender and the receiver are connected when the message is transmitted.

Answer (score 30):

[Telegram](https://telegram.org/):

- A fast and secure messaging alternative to WhatsApp.
- Focus is on speed and security.
- This free app supports group chats and you can even share videos upto 1 GB size.
- All your messages are in the cloud and you can easily access them from any of your devices.
- Telegram's *'Secret Chats'* feature offers end-to-end encryption.
- With Secret Chats **ON**, nothing is logged on its servers and you can automatically program the messages to self-destruct from both devices if needed.
- Platforms: [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/telegram-messenger/id686449807?mt=8) (official support), Linux, Windows, Chrome (unofficial support)

[Official Twitter Page](https://twitter.com/telegram).

Apparently over 1.8 million people joined it [yesterday](https://twitter.com/telegram/status/437374194998079489) 22/02/2014

**Also:**

At present there is currently a contest running until March 1st 2014 I believe:

[$200,000 to the hacker who can break Telegram](https://telegram.org/crypto_contest).

**EDIT:**

Articles of Interest:

- [Millions Flock to Telegram Messaging App After WhatsApp Outage](http://mashable.com/2014/02/23/telegram/).
- [Fighting DISHFIRE: The State of Mobile, Cross-Platform, Encrypted Messaging](https://missingm.co/2014/02/fighting-dishfire-the-state-of-mobile-cross-platform-encrypted-messaging/).

Other Apps that may interest you include:

- [Surespot](https://www.surespot.me/)
- [Wickr](https://www.mywickr.com/en/index.php)
- RedPhone & Text Secure by [Open Whisper Systems](https://whispersystems.org/)
- [Tango](http://www.tango.me/)

Comment: I do not recommend Telegram. It uses its own encryption scheme not based on well established protocols. This is a no-no in computer security, for the simple reason that writing secure encryption code is hard. Protocols need to be pounded on by others to make sure that they are good enough. Software manufacturers should only use proven encryption protocols (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/at-what-level-of-abstraction-should-a-developer-work-with-with-regards-to-crypto) and use them properly (https://www.schneier.com/essay-028.html).

Comment: @JanDoggen I'm not a Telegram user, but *"not based on well established protocols"* ? What about [AES, RSA, DH, SHA-1...](https://core.telegram.org/techfaq). Maybe you confused encryption and communications protocol? Their communications protocol is custom: "In order to achieve reliability on weak mobile connections as well as speed when dealing with large files (...), MTProto uses an original approach." The whole protocol seems [open and well documented](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto). So no *security through obscurity* here. Clients are open source, server will be soon, says Wikipedia.

Comment: There's still a debate about the security at e.g. http://unhandledexpression.com/2013/12/17/telegram-stand-back-we-know-maths/ and http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70546720222/telegrams-cryptanalysis-contest. The way it's going it looks like things are improving. The contest helps.

Comment: @JanDoggen, Dude the question asks for a whatsapp alternative, and this is it. If we actually **do** care security, we weren't be using a public app like this.

Comment: @Pacerier Do you mean public as in open source app? I think that's actually a plus for security/privacy conscious users.

Answer (score 12):

I recently started using [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org) and it seems to offer what you are looking for. You can read about their use of OTR (off the record) [here](https://jitsi.org/GSOC2009/OTR).

Let's see how it stacks up against your criteria:

- End-to-end encryption - Yes
- group chat - Yes
- search contacts in address book of the phone - **No**
- Ad free - Yes
- can cost up to € 2 once - It is free
- share photos, videos - Yes
- nice to have video chat - Yes
- Android support - Yes (alpha-version)
- iOS support - **No**

I use it on my Windows, Mac, and Android phone but I don't think it supports the iPhone (which might mean it does not work for you).

Comment: I would like to add https://tox.chat/ which uses OTR (Android still in some heavier development as it seems) and https://chatsecure.org/ (Only OSX AFAIK) which uses also OTR. But I think I will use Jitsi from *now*.

Answer (score 3):

I use [KakaoTalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KakaoTalk) (free). It has all the features you required except end-to-end encryption and personally I like that it's available on Windows and Mac.

It's the main instant message application in South Korea:

> KakaoTalk reached 57 million users registered on August 2012. On average, 24 million users are estimated to be using the app on a daily basis and over 3.4 billion messages are sent every day.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**Kontalk**](http://www.kontalk.org/). (Community-driven messaging ; A new way of communicating)

[image]

Information:

> Kontalk is a secure instant messenger, allowing you to send and receive text, image and voice messages (other file types coming soon) to and from other Kontalk users completely free of charge (*).
>
> - Your **phone number** is your **ID**. No usernames or passwords
> - It **automatically finds** other Kontalk users by looking at your address book, making it even easier to start chatting on Kontalk with your friends
> - **End-to-end encryption** ensures safe and private conversations, so that only you and the person you are talking to can read them
> - Your and all phone numbers used on the network are irreversibly encrypted
> - It **supports multiple devices**, making it very easy to start chatting on your phone and continue the conversation on your tablet
> - Based on open standards: **XMPP** and **OpenPGP**

Available on:

1. [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.kontalk)
2. [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kontalk)

The main benefit and characteristic is that it respects your [**freedom**](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)!
License: [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GNUGPLv3).

Sample screen-shot: [1](http://www.kontalk.org/images/app/app1.jpg), [2](http://www.kontalk.org/images/app/app2.jpg), [3](http://www.kontalk.org/images/app/app3.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is waaay late, but I can't believe anyone hasn't mentioned it!

## [BBM By BlackBerry](http://www.bbm.com/)

Your Requirements:

- End-to-end encryption: *It's by BlackBerry, need I say more? Ok, yes it has very strong end-to-end encryption*
- group chat: *Yes, as a simple chat, or also has the possibility to create a group where you can chat, share pictures, comment on the pictures, create lists, calendars, etc*
- search contacts in address book of the phone: *BBM is email and pin based, so cannot show you contacts based on mobile number like Whatsapp, but can by email.*
- Ad free: *Has small ads that appear every now and then in the feeds, but these are very unobtrusive, and be disabled by subscribing to the No-Ads subscription for $1 a month*
- can cost up to € 2 once: *Free, unless you want to extend it using the subscriptions*
- share photos, videos: *Yes, photos, videos, your location, voice notes, any file under 16mb, appointments, contact cards, etc*
- nice to have video chat: *Been present on BlackBerry 10 for a couple of years, they are in beta testing on Android and iOS at the moment (it may have even rolled out, I'm not sure)*
- Android and iOS support: *Yes, supports Android, iOS, Windows Phone, BlackBerry and Amazon Phones.*

Extra features:

- Individual Sent, Delivered and Read receipts for each message - (Whatsapp's was based on this)
- BBM Channels
- Stickers: Extra Large custom emoji which are sent as their own message. They are free or paid, and are added from the shop.

[image]

> BBM® is the best way to connect and share instant messages, pictures
> and more for free, in real time—all with speed, control and privacy.
>
> Have real conversations with friends on iPhone, Android™, Windows®
> Phone and BlackBerry®. And know when your messages are delivered and
> read. Plus, you can personalize with a profile pic, stickers and
> emoticons galore.
>
> There’s nothing like having a face-to-face conversation to express
> yourself. Switch your BBM™ chat to a BBM™ Video conversation with just
> a tap .You can even share the view from your camera, or what’s on your
> screen.

Answer (score 0):

Korean developed and Japan based [Line](http://line.me/en/) is the *number one*, feature laden, client in SE Asia these days, particularly in Thailand. Hardly anyone uses *Whatsapp* over here these days, especially since Facebook took over. *Line* is available for most platforms (Windows, OS X, iOS, Android), apart from Symbian and Linux, so no good for a Nokia N8 (which is what I currently have):

[image: Supported platforms]

Easy to use interface, and free to use and free of ads. Plenty of downloadable emoticons, emojis, games etc. It's becoming a bit of a platform in it's own right.

[image: Line's groups]

Fits all of your requirements, except end-to-end encryption. I used it a lot when I had an iDevice, a good fun comms app. Totally recommend.

China's [Wechat](http://www.wechat.com/) is another big messaging app over here too. And it is available for the N8.

### End to end encryption

However, [Line](http://line.me/en/) and [Wechat](http://www.wechat.com/) are ***not*** end-to-end encrypted messengers. For that, you are best off with [the Swiss **Threema**](https://threema.ch/en) (very big in Germany, again especially since Facebook ate Whatsapp) or one of the previously mentioned **Telegram**, **RedPhone**, **TextSecure** and **Surespot**. Threema I like a lot, as it has many of Whatsapp's features. No video calls though, although you can send video.

Obviously, your end choice of app will also depend on which platform your colleagues and friends are using, or are willing to switch to. Probably best to go for a bit of a mix. But my votes go to **Telegram**, **Threema** and **Line**.

Answer (score 0):

### [Actor.im](https://actor.im/)

[image]

- group chat
- ad free (it's totally open source: client and server)
- totally free
- support for markdown
- share files, photos
- clients available for android, ios and web
- [What about encryption?](https://actor.im/#faq)

  > We use 256-bit AES encryption for transmitting App to Server. In
  >   Enterprise edition it is available full end-to-end encryption.